# Automation test with jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using C#, Visual studio, selenium.
I'm using Jenkins to execute my automation tests.
Every test begin with method that update XML file locate in my solution.

My problem is that: Sometimes the tests fail because of exception: "Access to the path XXX is denied".
When I change the directory to be writeable the tests pass, but, I need to do it everytime, so, how can I change it to work properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I change the directory to be writeable"? Would that not be something that needs to be done if you want to write to it? And how can the tests fail only sometimes, if it's not writable in general?

Comment: I don't think we can really help you decide your write permissions in your own personal environment. Perhaps you have lots of sub-directories and you just need to set write permissions on the parent folder?